# Compile Opencv With IEEE Support

Tags: macos, opencv, cmake, libdc1394

System:
Mac OS 10.13
Opencv 3.4.7
Libdc1394-2.2.6

I need to build Opencv from source with Cmake GUI to be used with Python 3.7, and under "DC1394" after configuring it, it states "No"

I have installed Libdc1394 with the "./configure && make, && make install" command and can verify the location of the files, but Cmake still can not found the library.

What else can be done to compile Opencv with DC1394?

Comment: Did you find any solution to the problem? I'm also facing a similar problem. I cannot set buffer size using cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 1) in opencv-python version 4.1.2 on Ubuntu 18..04. The reason is that CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE needs DC1394 and I have only FFMPEG backend?